# Javascript countdown timer that uses cookies

Tags: javascript, alert

Can anyone help me? I need to make a javascript countdown timer that uses cookies. When a user refreshes the page, the timer does not change until fixed time ends. I am making an online examination system. I want one question per page and 30 minutes   as the overall time.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic before posting questions like this. Voting to close this as this doesn't show any effort

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I would go with localStorage instead of cookies; check MDN for a good specification, or just type "localStorage" in your browser's JavaScript console and see the methods. One getter,  one setter, simple and straightforward. Just store the calculated end time, and show the countdown timer as stored time minus current time.

Use cookies only if it's likely that your users will arrive from obsolete browsers.

Also, if you want to make it absolutely sure, there's no clientside solution so you might want to do an AJAX call to start the timer and then read it with another call on each reload. I'd definitely do it like this, since localStorage is easy to tamper with; but on the other hand, it's easier.

More details for more details ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the time from the server once your user log in. I mean, anyone could cheat the timer if it's stored locally.